# Angular 1 $http does not wait for response

Tags: http, callback, angular1.6

I am trying to make an http get request but the code goes directly to the .then(), and just after finish the Angular part, it goes to the backend. What I am doing wrong?
This is my service:

```
angular.module('project').factory('ConversationService',  function($http, $q){
```

var factory = {};
    factory.fazConversa = fazConversa;

```
function fazConversa(params){
    let url =  `/conversation?text=${params.mensagem}&context=${params.context}`;
         let data = {
             text: params.mensagem,
             context: params.context
         }
         $http.get(url).then(function(resposta){
            console.log(resposta);
            resolve(resposta);
         });
}

return factory;
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then` is a promise construct, in which case it will only be invoked asynchronously if `$http.get(url)` returns a promise, which eventually becomes resolved. As you seem to be getting synchronous behaviour, then I am guessing the it isn't returning a promise.

In which case you should be using the normal `$http.get(url)` async response function of `.success`

Comment: ohhh, I was pasting here my backend when I realized the issue. I am not returning the response, I am returning something else... Thank you!!!